# How do I take variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I made an AJAX request so that when I select drop down the results will be out. I am confused. The problem is that only a table is displayed. How come the data comes from the variable `$grade` (calculation of grade), the variable `$value` (calculation of total value)?

I try to get the element. `$grade` instead it is undefined

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#kategori').on('change', function(e){
            var id = e.target.value;
            $.get('/khs/khs_semester/' + id, function(data){
                console.log(id);
                console.log(data);
                $('#khs').empty();
                $.each(data, function(index, element){
                    $('#khs').append("<tr><td>" + element.kode_mk + "</td><td>" + element.nama_mk + "</td>" + "<td>" + element.semester + "</td><td>" + element.jml_sks + "</td><td>" + element.$grade + "</td></tr>");
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="100">KODE MK</th>
            <th width="350">NAMA MK</th>
            <th width="50">SEMESTER</th>
            <th width="50">SKS</th>
            <th width="50">GRADE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="khs">
        @foreach($mahasiswa as $row)
            @php

                $nilai = hitung_nilai($row->id);
                $grade = hitung_grade($nilai);
                $mutu  = hitung_mutu($grade);

            @endphp
            <tr>

                <td>{{ $row->kode_mk }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->nama_mk }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->semester }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->jml_sks}}</td>
                <td>{{ $grade }}</td>
                <td>{{ $mutu*$row->jml_sks }}</td>
            </tr>
            @php
                $totalSKS=$totalSKS+$row->jml_sks;
                $totalMutu = $totalMutu+$mutu*$row->jml_sks;
            @endphp
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Error, Undefined]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What might help you is to identify each row by an ID, it could be an ID in the `<tr id="KM003">` or in the specific TD of the grade, like `<td id="KM003Grade">` so you could get the grade by the students code like: `var Name = $('#IDused').innerHTML;`

If you use by the ROW approach, you could use a class in each child TD to identify the attribute, for example:

```
<tr id="km003">
<td class="kode">{{ $row->kode_mk }}</td>
<td class="nama">{{ $row->nama_mk }}</td>
<td class="semester">{{ $row->semester }}</td>
<td class="jml_sks">{{ $row->jml_sks}}</td>
<td class="grade">{{ $grade }}</td>
</tr>
```

and then you could get the value by `var grade = $("#km003 .grade").innerHTML;`

Comment: sorry, where is it put? i don't understand ajax

Comment: @KhaizBadaruTammam this is JQuery basically, what you want to do is to identify each row by an ID, it could be an ID in the `<tr id="KM003">`or in the specific TD of the grade, like `<td id="KM003Grade">` so you could get the grade by the students code...

Comment: If you use by the ROW, like the first example, you could use a class in each child TD to identify the attribute, for example:  
`<tr id="km003">`
`      <td class="kode">{{ $row->kode_mk }}</td>`
`      <td class="nama">{{ $row->nama_mk }}</td>`
`      <td class="semester">{{ $row->semester }}</td>`
`      <td class="jml_sks">{{ $row->jml_sks}}</td>`
`      <td class="grade">{{ $grade }}</td><br />`
`</tr>`

Comment: im having trouble to indent the code here, but basically after you use an id to the row, you could acess by JQuery using `$('#km003 .grade).innerHTML;`

Comment: a nice and fast way to find out if the code is ok, if it works, is using the google devtools, `Ctrl+Shift+I` to open and you can type on console

Comment: Reading the entire code again, there's some other problems...`<td>{{ $row->kode_mk }}</td>`and grade is not a $row property, its only `<td>{{ $grade }}</td>` is that right? grade is the same for every row or each row will carry its own grade?? if each row has a diff grade, then it would be `<td>{{ $row->grade }}</td>`

Comment: Grade comes from calculations : $nilai = hitung_nilai($row->id);
                $grade = hitung_grade($nilai);
                $mutu  = hitung_mutu($grade);

Comment: `hitung_nilai($row->id);`, `hitung_grade($nilai);`, `hitung_mutu($grade);` are these functions returning the results properly? maybe in you arrangement, the order is mixed up, example, you might have to use some value you are only calculating further ahead on the function... you need to make sure they are returning a valid value and that they get the result before being used in another function...